# How to run an animation in a table cell if the value changes

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify + nuxt to create my web application, how could I apply an animation to a cell if its value changes?

I tried to add a ref to my table element like:
`<v-data-table ref="table" :items="data" :headers="headers"/>`

and then

`$this.$refs.table.$el.addEventListener('change', func)`

but nothing happened... anyone can give a light?

Comment: Please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: added a MRE as a download link

Comment: A table doesn't have a `value` only text. Only `<input>` (and related fields) have a change event. I think you might want to listen when the table object itself changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More than *"value"* I believe you're interested in TD cell *"textContent"* change.

The best would be tap in the function that does the content update.
Otherwise, use  [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) on the `childList` property for every TD of a specific table:

```js
const contentsObserver = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach(mu => {
    if (mu.type === "childList") {
      mu.target.classList.add("is-changed");
      mu.target.addEventListener("animationend", () => {
        mu.target.classList.remove("is-changed");
      }, {once: true});
    }
  });
});

const elsTD = document.querySelectorAll("tbody td");
elsTD.forEach(elTD => contentsObserver.observe(elTD, {childList: true}));


// Demo: dynamic textContent change
const rand = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
const changeText = () => {
  const index = ~~rand(0, elsTD.length);
  const elTDActive = elsTD[index];
  elTDActive.textContent = rand(1, 99).toFixed(2);
  setTimeout(changeText, rand(300, 1300));
}
changeText();
```

```css
td, th {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font: 1rem/1.5 monospace;
}

.is-changed {
  animation: blink 1s;
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    background: fuchsia;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Foo</th>
      <th>Bar</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Baz</th>
      <td>23.00</td>
      <td>56.45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Daz</th>
      <td>34.46</td>
      <td>89,20</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: does not worked in vuetify.. can u try to apply this in MRE?

Answer (score 0):

Using with vuetify v2:

```
mutateMethod (mutations, mu) {
      mutations.forEach((mu) => {
        if (mu.type === 'characterData') {
          let parentNode = mu.target.parentElement
          if (parentNode.tagName === 'SPAN') { parentNode = parentNode.parentElement }
          parentNode.classList.add('is-changed')
          parentNode.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
            parentNode.classList.remove('is-changed')
          })
        }
      })
    },
```

Table

```
<v-data-table v-mutate="mutateMethod"/>
```